# Populate fields with auth user info when checkbox is checked

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have the form below for a user to register in a congress.

There is this section where the user inser the name and surname of each participant.

I have a checkbox "Fill the following fields with the authenticated user information." and if the user select this checkbox I want to populate the input fields name and surname with the `name` and `surname` of the authenticated user. Do you know how to achieve that?

The checkbox is only to allow the user to, if he is also a participant, instead of enter his name and surname click in the checkbox and he dont need to enter his name and surname, its automatic.

```
@foreach(range(1,$selectedRtype['quantity']) as $test)
    <h6>Participant - 1 - {{$test}}</h6>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="" value="">
        <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="exampleRadios1">
            <span class="mr-auto">Fill the following fields with the authenticated user information.</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
        <label for="participant_name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="participant_name[]" required class="form-control" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
        <label for="participant_surname" class="text-gray">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="participant_surname[]" value="">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Full form:

```
 <form method="post" id="step1" action="">
        {{csrf_field()}}

        @if (!empty($allParticipants))
            @if($allParticipants == 1)
                <p>Please enter the following information:.</p>

                @foreach($selectedRtypes as $selectedRtype)
                    @foreach(range(1,$selectedRtype['quantity']) as $test)
                        <h6>Participant - 1 - {{$test}}</h6>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="" value="referencias">
                            <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="exampleRadios1">
                                <span class="mr-auto">Fill the following fields with the authenticated user information.</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                            <label for="participant_name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="participant_name[]" required class="form-control" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                            <label for="participant_surname" class="text-gray">Surname</label>
                            <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="participant_surname[]" value="">
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            @endif

        @else
            <p>Is not necessary additional info the tickets will be send to  Auth::user()->email.</p>
        @endif
        <input type="submit" href="#step2free"
               id="goToStep2Free" class="btn btn-primary btn float-right next-step" value="Go to step 2"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to do this.

Just initialize the variables with the fields you want:

```
<script>
    var name = {{ $name }}
    var surname = {{ $surname }}
</script>
```

And put a listener at the checkbox onchange event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checkboxId').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#inputNameId').val(name);
            $('#inputSurnameId').val(surname);
        } else {
           $('#inputNameId').val('');
           $('#inputSurnameId').val('');
        }  
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, also do you know how to show the checkbox  only once? Only for the first participant name and surname fields? Because as it is if the user selected 2 tickets in the previous page and then appears twice name and surname fields it appears always twice the checkbox but I just want to show one checkbox.

Comment: The issue is that I want "div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name=""">
                            <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="exampleRadios1">
                                <span class="mr-auto">Fill the following fields with the authenticated user information.</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>" after "                        <h6>Participant - 1 - {{$test}}</h6>". So I dont know how that can be achieved.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to show only for the first item or for all items but once clicked, disappear all others?

Comment: I want to show the checbkox associated with only the first set of name and surname fields, only for the first iteration of the for.

Comment: Then you can use a `for` loop beginning in the second element instead of a foreach and, before it runs, put the first form manually with the checkbox. http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/87/using-for-control-structures-in-blade